# format properly output using setw()

Tags: c++

Is there any other way of doing this? if section of this code make it work but is there any way of using setw() to organize (*) properly?

```
void showTheater(char theater[][20],int row,int seat)
{
    cout << "Seats:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= row; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j <= seat; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0) {
                cout << "Row " << i;
            }
            else if (i < 10) {
                cout << setw(3) << theater[row][seat];
            }
            else {
                cout <<" " << theater[row][seat]<<" ";
            }

        }

        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

output without writing if section:

> ```
> Seats:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
> Row 0  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 1  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 2  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 3  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 4  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 5  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 6  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 7  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 8  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 9  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 10  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 11  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 12  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 13  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 14  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 15  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> ```

output with if section:

> ```
> Seats:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
> Row 0  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 1  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 2  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 3  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 4  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 5  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 6  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 7  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 8  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 9  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 10 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 11 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 12 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 13 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 14 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> Row 15 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> ```

Comment: Apply `setw` to `i` in `cout << "Row " << i;` as well. Then you wouldn't need the `if`.

Comment: you want only the stars aligned, or also the headers?

Comment: use printf(), sometimes better than messing around with cout

Comment: only the stars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use `std::setw` (in conjunction with `std::left`) for the index of the row. Here is the code. Note that now the stars are also aligned with the headers. In the posted code, there was also an error on the indices of `theater`.

```
void showTheater(char theater[][20], int row, int seat) {
    std::vector<int> Seats (seat);
    for (int i = 0; i < seat; i++) Seats[i] = i;
    std::cout << "Seats:";
    for (int i = 0; i < seat; i++) std::cout << std::setw(3) << Seats[i] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        std::cout << "Row " << std::setw(2) << std::left << i << " ";
        for (int j = 0; j < seat; j++) {
            std::cout << " " << theater[i][i] << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

EDIT: I just discovered that HolyBlackCat already mentioned the way to align the stars. Sorry. At least I also aligned the Headers and suppressed the useless `setw`for printing the chars.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You welcome. If this solution satisfies you, could you please accept this answer?